# Steam Web API not retrieving user reviews

Tags: steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I have been trying to get some user reviews from an app on Steam using their API which is documented [here](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews). However, some of the requests return only the JSON `{"success":2}` and nothing else.

You can try these two requests on your browser:

[Miner Ultra Adventures Steam Web API reviews](https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/585780?json=1&filter=recent): this request returns `{"success":1,"query_summary":{...},"reviews":[...]}` and if you open this [Steam Community page](https://steamcommunity.com/app/585780/reviews/?filterLanguage=english&p=1&browsefilter=mostrecent) you can check that the game has reviews and they are being retrieved correctly.

[UFO: Afterlight - Old Version](https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/7500?json=1&filter=recent): this returns `{"success":2}` but when you open the [game's Steam Community page](https://steamcommunity.com/app/7500/reviews/?filterLanguage=english&p=1&browsefilter=mostrecent) you can see that the game has several reviews but they are not being retrieved.

I have not found any information on this response code. I do not think this matters but I am using two Python libraries: [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Edit:

I have found this [unofficial website](https://steamerrors.com/) that has response codes. It seems to be a generic error and I still do not know how to access some app reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UFO: Afterlight - Old Version** was removed from Steam store.
You will get same response with any other game Title that has been removed from Store.